# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.ex.bul.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.ex.bul.service.UserService' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, postman

I tried a simple Spring-boot project for learning structure. When I add a simple method for testing postman but I get an this error. (Parameter 0 of constructor in com.ex.bul.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.ex.bul.service.UserService' that could not be found).

*UserController class*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers(){
        List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(users);// ResponseEntity.ok() HTTP 200e denk geliyor
    }
```

*UserService*

```
public interface UserService {

    User createUser(User users);
    List<User> getUsers();
}
```

*UserServiceImpl*

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

*UserRepository*

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

*Application.class*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.ex.bul.controller"})
public class BulApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BulApplication.class, args);
    }
```

error:

```
*****************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.ex.bul.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.ex.bul.service.UserService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ex.bul.service.UserService' in your configuration.
**
```

What can I do for fixing?

this is pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ex.bul</groupId>
    <artifactId>bul</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bul</name>
    <description>bul</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe5Kb.png)

Comment: Just remove this line: `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.ex.bul.controller"})`

Comment: Removed the ` @Autowired` from your constructors... remove `javax.persistence` dep check the documentation of spring boot 3+ because it used jakarta instead. Why defining `UserService` interface? Do you have multiple implementations ? I doubt that... also use `@GetMapping` instead of ` @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)` .. ?

Comment: @Mar-Z I tried but when I remove this annotation I get same error for service-repository class (Parameter 0 of constructor in com.ex.bul.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.ex.bul.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.)

Comment: @khmarbaise I changed with jakarta but it has same error. Yes I've multiple impl.

Comment: If you havem ultiple impl. which one should be used for inejction? In such case there should be a qualifier to distinguish them?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with your code.

1. Wrong configuration of Spring component scanning.

Currently you are scanning only the `com.ex.bul.controller` package. But you have Spring components in other packages too. The best way (recommended by Spring Boot documentation) is to scan all packages starting with the one where the main application class resides.

**Solution**

Remove the annotation

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.ex.bul.controller"})
```

2. Wrong dependencies in `pom.xml`

Currently you are mixing the new version of JPA with the old one from Spring Boot 2.

**Solution**

Remove this part:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

and use only this instead:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

If you get compile errors due to missing package `javax.persistence` just replace them with `jakarta.persistence`.